# How is R producing these ARIMA forecasts?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to understand what R is doing to produce forecasts for a particular ARIMA model I fitted. I used R to fit an ARIMA (1,0,0)(1,0,0)[5] error model with the following data.

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 113 
Frequency = 1 
  [1] -7.14350665 -6.73165280 -7.83548281 -4.30565291 -2.88642538 -8.02231296
  [7] -1.51434007 -7.03125494 -4.90820782 -7.37263594 -6.99763160  1.61536844
 [13] -6.65929571 -7.08597878 -6.71677058 -6.84377671 -0.67738303 -5.94119848
 [19] -2.60765436 -0.72883740 -2.19761607 -3.26346896 -7.12577627 -2.04590492
 [25] -0.10615455 -5.74073754 -0.55885525 -4.45595224 -2.31422721 -1.51466722
 [31] -1.07916082 -7.14001403  2.56805438 -1.00693993 -1.86195796 -4.40997737
 [37] -3.03161377 -2.22823164 -5.75399905 -5.74919856 -5.89791612 -1.45997721
 [43] -1.50145004  0.87110026  0.80863650 -5.51231682 -5.41865691 -5.48808301
 [49] -5.73650485 -5.16338305 -5.93872588 -1.60867764 -4.96849580 -5.68901940
 [55] -0.24450719 -5.43569136  0.21061774  0.17970190  0.49289760 -4.95969802
 [61] -5.38250360  0.12825664 -4.96919159  4.91420400 -1.64231438 -5.04322677
 [67] -4.85993664 -5.57683987  4.49079441  2.06421751 -0.85523832 -0.75936491
 [73] -0.73331619 -0.67445696  0.47672500  0.52226478 -5.01028727 -0.34117444
 [79]  0.06680984  2.85285597  2.19874190 -4.79919738  3.84652672 -1.56689807
 [85]  5.17368392  0.48262304  0.67389789  0.57239262  0.51711997  0.67139680
 [91]  1.01257370  1.08726740  1.17538371  3.44020625  2.81917055  2.46195644
 [97] -0.49988983  2.44369015  3.79962767  1.68364602  4.22746379  0.36932087
[103]  2.33035539  3.31986940 -0.29803386  4.31593086  2.18883434  0.64759198
[109]  2.44158613  1.65587246 -0.35450341 -0.12559422  3.60052663
```

R fitted the following seasonal model.

```
Series: tsdata 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[5] with drift 

Coefficients:
     ar1    sar1  intercept   drift
  0.0069  0.2615    -5.8280  0.0724
s.e.  0.0954  0.0916     0.6218  0.0094

sigma^2 estimated as 6.491:  log likelihood=-264.16
AIC=538.32   AICc=538.88   BIC=551.96
```

I used the following code to do this:

```
modeltest<-Arima(tsdata,order=c(1,0,0), seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,0),period = 5), include.drift=TRUE)
```

The residuals of the model are as follows:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 113 
Frequency = 1 
  [1] -1.33958175 -1.00272634 -2.14026149  1.20469075  2.48405984 -2.28224209
  [7]  4.09675615 -1.22867217 -0.04582958 -2.94278213 -1.25813615  5.58791270
 [13] -1.34463507 -2.33255587 -1.36514602 -1.65029884  2.21201128 -0.96779960
 [19]  2.44561312  4.15104160  2.65010973 -0.07162532 -2.59191657  1.58018249
 [25]  2.94647973 -2.36704291  3.07669244  0.09897993  0.87898341  1.11255235
 [31]  2.96656604 -4.51574308  6.20955663  1.94741957  0.85870792 -1.84896031
 [37]  1.07975326 -0.72931622 -3.36124250 -3.16805913 -2.70505533  1.31574830
 [43]  0.98297984  4.22626918  4.08675736 -2.24794822 -3.32472654 -3.42903781
 [49] -4.35063205 -3.80827087 -2.98764901  1.25876933 -2.16565186 -2.85126006
 [55]  2.39479697 -2.68318935  1.81198201  2.57556037  3.01826552 -3.91477077
 [61] -2.98562252  0.98893558 -4.18131624  5.60216092  0.35101571 -2.95704586
 [67] -4.24538732 -3.67357541  3.75193158  2.93541617  0.85721847  0.86606202
 [73]  1.02618596 -1.60249048  0.14796761  0.89163639 -4.72465092 -0.07713191
 [79]  0.23024025  2.65942770  1.92319139 -3.67632002  3.73346870 -1.89091287
 [85]  4.10599741 -0.50851438  1.49099180 -0.93863870  0.38505445 -1.28598866
 [91]  0.24003801  0.20081530  0.26222277  2.48762505  1.75744694  1.26247814
 [97] -1.76891114  1.11908664  1.80949315 -0.20241804  2.39520048 -0.75959536
[103]  0.39977440  0.97337604 -2.14859781  1.76812047  0.56973994 -1.52974926
[109] -0.03346987  0.06333687 -3.20791607 -2.45362229  1.61708100
```

Finally, R produced the following forecasts:

```
Point Forecast       Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
114       2.534172 -0.73096624 5.799310 -2.459426 7.527769
115       2.371187 -0.89402849 5.636402 -2.622529 7.364903
116       1.898794 -1.36642181 5.164009 -3.094922 6.892510
117       2.012113 -1.25310213 5.277329 -2.981603 7.005829
118       3.040056 -0.22515960 6.305271 -1.953660 8.033772
119       2.814627 -0.56040282 6.189657 -2.347036 7.976289
120       2.825455 -0.54957938 6.200490 -2.336215 7.987126
121       2.755365 -0.61967014 6.130400 -2.406306 7.917035
122       2.838455 -0.53657995 6.213490 -2.323215 8.000125
123       3.160746 -0.21428935 6.535780 -2.000925 8.322416
124       3.155243 -0.22717250 6.537659 -2.017715 8.328201
125       3.211529 -0.17088706 6.593945 -1.961430 8.384488
126       3.246652 -0.13576403 6.629068 -1.926307 8.419611
127       3.321836 -0.06057973 6.704252 -1.851123 8.494795
128       3.459578  0.07716242 6.841994 -1.713380 8.632537
129       3.511593  0.12867294 6.894513 -1.662137 8.685323
130       3.579767  0.19684709 6.962687 -1.593963 8.753497
131       3.642407  0.25948658 7.025327 -1.531323 8.816137
132       3.715523  0.33260326 7.098444 -1.458207 8.889253
133       3.805001  0.42208063 7.187921 -1.368729 8.978731
134       3.872058  0.48910331 7.255013 -1.301725 9.045841
135       3.943341  0.56038664 7.326296 -1.230441 9.117124
136       4.013177  0.63022248 7.396132 -1.160606 9.186960
```

I would really like to understand the actual equation that's being used to generate these forecasts. I'm not too clear on how ARIMA error models with seasonal components work.

Comment: You should look at any time series book to understand the theory. There are so many books that discuss these models and some are free to download. There are also tons of lecture notes on this over the internet.

Comment: Also, there are tons of related threads here on CV. Could you focus your question a bit more?